# Dynamically generated key traverse nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to traverse json object to get value of a key from it and was able to do that.

**This is the code which i have tried** :

```js
var json = {
  "SERVICE": {
    "Support1": {
      "MODULE": {
        "Something": {
          "SUBMODULE": {
            "Abc": {
              "PRODUCT": [{
                "productName": "something1",
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Support2": {
      "MODULE": {
        "Something2": {
          "SUBMODULE": {
            "Abc2": {
              "PRODUCT": [{
                "productName": "something10",
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
}

Object.keys(json.SERVICE).forEach(service => {
  var module = Object.keys(json.SERVICE[service].MODULE);
  module.forEach(modules => {
    var sub_module = Object.keys(json.SERVICE[service].MODULE[modules].SUBMODULE);
    sub_module.forEach(products => {
      var products = json.SERVICE[service].MODULE[modules].SUBMODULE[products].PRODUCT;
      products.forEach(value => {
        console.log(value.productName)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Is there any other way to traverse this dynamic json because multiple *forEach* doesn't seems proper or can i get the **"PRODUCT"** key values directly without traversing ?

Thank you for helping .

Comment: might help? https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#get

Comment: @cmgchess [You don't (may not) need Lodash/Underscore](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive function can be used here instead.

```js
let o={SERVICE:{Support1:{MODULE:{Something:{SUBMODULE:{Abc:{PRODUCT:[{productName:"something1"}]}}}}},Support2:{MODULE:{Something2:{SUBMODULE:{Abc2:{PRODUCT:[{productName:"something10"}]}}}}}}};
const getProducts = o => Object.entries(o).flatMap(([k, v]) => k === 'PRODUCT' ? 
  v.map(p => p.productName) : v === Object(v) ? getProducts(v) : []);
console.log(getProducts(o));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping . I am trying your solution will update you if this works with my code .

Answer (score 1):

Just create recursive function like code below to solve that problem:

```js
var json = {"SERVICE":{"Support1":{"MODULE":{"Something":{"SUBMODULE":{"Abc":{"PRODUCT":[{"productName":"something1","productCode":"1234","productHierarchy":"yz"},{"productName":"something2","productCode":"124","productHierarchy":"ddd"}]}}}}},"Support2":{"MODULE":{"Something2":{"SUBMODULE":{"Abc2":{"PRODUCT":[{"productName":"something1","productCode":"1234","productHierarchy":"yz"},{"productName":"something2","productCode":"124","productHierarchy":"ddd"}]}}}}}}};

let getData = (value, result = []) => {
  if(value instanceof Object || value instanceof Array) {
    for(v in value) {
      if (typeof value[v] === 'string') {
        result.push(value);
      } else {
        getData(value[v], result);
      }
    }
  }
  return [...new Set(result.map(v => JSON.stringify(v)))].map(v => JSON.parse(v));
}

console.log(getData(json));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering . I tried your solution its giving product in array is it possible to return whole json object of product like @brk answer does ? because there will be more key/value inside product array and it will become complicated to get all values .

Comment: Yes, It is possible. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Tried it . Now , its giving duplicated json array . Please see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r18jb3q4/).

Comment: Now its not giving duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Javascript already has a built-in json walker: `JSON.strinfigy`:

```
let products = []

JSON.stringify(json, (k, v) => {
    if (k === 'productName')
        products.push(v)
    return v
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion

```js
const json = {
  "SERVICE": {
    "Support1": {
      "MODULE": {
        "Something": {
          "SUBMODULE": {
            "Abc": {
              "PRODUCT": [{
                "productName": "something1",
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Support2": {
      "MODULE": {
        "Something2": {
          "SUBMODULE": {
            "Abc2": {
              "PRODUCT": [{
                "productName": "something10",
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
}

function doRecursion(json, key) {
  for (let objectKey in json) {
    if (objectKey === key) {
      return json[objectKey]

    } else if (typeof json[objectKey] === 'object') {
      return doRecursion(json[objectKey], key)
    }
  }
}

console.log(doRecursion(json, 'PRODUCT'))
```